# Change .mp3 Metadata Title and Author in Python 3.3

Tags: python, mp3, metadata

I have looked around the web for about half an hour. I have found a couple libraries that do this, but none (that I can find) work in python 3. All of them are programmed towards 2.7. I know that there is the 2to3.py tool in the python 3 package, but it doesn't work correctly for the programs that I have tried.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`mutagenx`](https://github.com/LordSputnik/mutagen) ([PyPI listing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagenx) currently down). The original mutagen is apparently slowly being ported to support Python 3, meanwhile `mutagenx` which started off supporting Python 3 now supports Python 2 as well (also see the [discussion](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/issues/detail?id=27) on the request for Python 3 support on the mutagen bug tracker)

Comment: When trying to install, I get the following
    error: package directory 'mutagenx' does not exist

Comment: How are you performing the installation?

Comment: Navigating to the directory, then using the command (win8): python setup.py install

Comment: Switch to the mutagenx1.22.1 branch first, I think the latest trunk code does not build for some reason.

Comment: Ok the installation worked. Now, do I just copy the mutagenx directory to my working directory and import it? Sorry, I am quite new with these extra python libraries since I have only recently been using python for actual program use.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the example given in the `TUTORIAL` file - if the `install` step puts mutagenx in a directory that is part of your `PYTHONPATH` then you should be all set. If that does not work, find out where mutagenx ended up being installed.

Comment: Thanks, it did in fact install to my python path. Is there any way to have it more portable so if I were to share the program I could easily call the library?

Comment: Look up venv  - it's a bit more convoluted to set up in py3 than the equivalent virtualenv for py2, since they didn't include the pip installer